# Magento2 Grid: Select all disabled with two dropdown filters

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, order-grid

A client running a magento 2.3.2. store noted that he can not use the Select All when two Filters are enabled. This pertains to the Magento Grid with orders on the Sales page. The filters the client is using are Status & Storeview.

I tested this behavior and can confirm that when he uses 2 Dropdown filters, the Select All functionality gets disabled. The disabling works through adding a 'disabled' attribute to both the input & button element. Other combinations of filters do not seem to have this behavior. When I manually remove the attributes (devtools) the functionality seems to work properly.

My questions.

1. Is there a good reason why the 'Select All' gets disabled on selecting 2 dropdown filters? The disabling seems intentional, so I figure it is not a bug?
2. If there is no reason, I might want to adjust this behavior. Could you point me in the right direction to where this behavior is set?

I appreciate any helpful input.